# For each n, find an example of a critical 2-connected graph with a vertex of degree at least n.

Tags: graph-theory

**Definition:**
Let G be a critical 2-connected graph; this means that G is 2-connected but no graph G − e for e ∈ E(G) is 2-connected.

**Question**
For each n, find an example of a critical 2-connected graph with a vertex of degree at least n.

I am pretty new to this, would you give me some examples or hint?

My first thought is a tree, which is minimally connected. Say n = 5, I have a tree T with only 4 edges.Removing any 1 edge, T is disconnected. Is this what the question is looking for? would any tree with order n work for this example? Please help me to understand this question better.

Comment: A tree is not 2-connected, though. Remember that "2-connected" means that you can remove any _single_ vertex and what is left must still be connected.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm Ok, thanks, but now I am stuck! do you have an example?

Comment: Well -- you need to find an example of a graph with a vertex of degree $n$, so start by drawing a vertex and $n$ neighbors to it. Since the graph needs to be 2-connected, you need to add more vertices/edges such that the graph stays connected if your degree-$n$ vertex is removed. Can you find a way to do that such that the result is _critical_?

Comment: @ Henning Makholm $C_{i}$ has i vertices, if I add a vertex in the center to form a wheel graph, then the new vertex v has degree i. by removing it, the cycle graph is still connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2-connected means the graph is connected, and if you remove any edge it is still connected. In practice this means the graph must contain a connected simple subgraph in which every vertex must have a degree of at least 2. (We'll just consider simple graphs because anything else is just redundant)

If you have a tree, the vertices on the "ends" of the graph only have one edge, so it doesn't work.

The easiest example of a graph that's definitely critically 2-connected is a cycle graph. This is where (if you label your vertices from 1 to k), there's an edge between vertex 1 and vertex 2, vertex 2 and vertex 3, ..., vertex k-1 and vertex k, and vertex k and vertex 1. Now if you remove any edge, say the edge between vertex 1 and vertex 2, then vertex 1 has degree 1 and vertex 2 has degree 1, so they are no longer 2-connected. Good. However you had an extra condition - for each n, you need an example where there is a vertex of degree at least n. For a cycle graph, every vertex has degree 2, so this example only works for n = 1, 2.

Intuitively you need to have one vertex with many edges coming off it, but each of these edges can only connect to a vertex with one other edge. Otherwise if you removed an edge adjacent to the "vertex with degree at least n", it will still be 2-connected and hence you graph wasn't critical. Well the key is to combine this idea with cycle graphs. (All you need are 3-cycles.)

Visualise $G_1$ to be a graph with 3 vertices, where each of these verticies are connected to the other two. You end up with a cycle-graph that looks like a triangle, critically 2-connected. Now make a copy of this graph which shares a vertex with $G_1$. You have a "central vertex" with degree 4, and four verticies around it which all have degree 2. It looks like a bow-tie. This is still critically 2-connected because every edge connects to a vertex with only one other edge. However, we now have a graph for n = 1, 2, 3, and 4.

In the same way, for any n, you:

1. need to consider any even k greater than it
2. have k edges radiating out from one vertex
3. add a vertex to the end of each of these edges
4. add an edge between every pair of these vertices.

Here's an example of a graph which is critically 2-connected with a vertex of at least degree 8.

[image: n = 8]

Comment: @ Shanye2020 thanks for your thoughtful explaination. In another word, it is just a wheel? right? with the added vertex that has degree n as the hub and each of its edges acting as a spoke? and the edges between any pair of the outer vertices act as part of the wheel?

Comment: Nope if it's a wheel graph then it's not critical, you need to make sure you don't have "too many edges"on the outside. It's like a combination of lots of triangles, I'm not sure if it has a name.

Comment: This is not a 2-connected graph...

Comment: @richarddedekind is right. The definition of $2$-connected requires that the graph is connected after any *vertex* is deleted (not edge).